# how do i bind dropdown list using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have a dropdown list, and i want to know how can i bind my drop down list client side with data coming from the database....

another question is..i am validating a drop down list...so far thsi is what i have:

```
if ($("select[id*=drpR]").val() == "Choose") {
    $("#lblmessage").html("Please choose Reseller!");
    return false;//To prevent the form from submitting.
}
else {
    return true;
}
```

my problem here, is that it doesn't show the Message in the else part..
can anybody help me..?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
if ($("#drpR").val() != '') 
{            //Try to change here                    
      return true;                    
}
else {
      $("#lblmessage").html("Please choose type!");
      return false;
}
```

and also put empty value for the default option i.e. like

```
<option value=''>--Choose--</option>
```

Comment: still the same....it prevent from moving to the next page but doesn't show the message...

Comment: hmm...but i am using databind() for my drop down list..
and i also have this line
    drpR.Items.Inser(0, "Choose");

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($("#drpR").val().length != 0 && $("#drpR").val() != "Choose") {
// or try if ($("#drpR").val() != "" && $("#drpR").val() != "Choose") {
    return true;
}
else {
    $("#lblmessage").html("Please choose type!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you for you suggestions too...but i figured it out... :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please try This Code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: "{}",
url: "AjaxInJquery.aspx/GetCityData",
dataType: "json",
success: ajaxSucceess,
error: ajaxError
});
function ajaxSucceess(response) {
$.each(response.d, function (key, value) {
$("#ddlCategory").append($("<option>       </option>").val(value.CityId).html(value.Cityname));
});
}
function ajaxError(response) {
alert(response.status + ' ' + response.statusText);
}
});
</script>
```

Please Refer This Link To Explorer More [Reference Link](http://hamidseta.blogspot.in/2012/02/bind-dropdownlist-using-jquery-ajax-in.html)

Hope It will helps you